# Требуется wrapper для v8 API

Tags: v8

Добрый день!
Хотелось бы найти интерфейсную обёртку для Google-овского JS движка v8 (подразумеваю: встраиваемого в НЕ web-приложение в качестве движка сценариев).

Суть вопроса в том, что даже простейшие примеры - shell и process (официальные и единственные рабочие примеры для v8, которые мне, на настоящий момент, удалось найти) весьма напоминают spagetti-код (из-за избытка деталей, затруднительно понять логику приложения) и если их ещё можно прочитать, то работа с кодом, функциональность которого существенно больше чем в них, представляется весьма затруднительной.

По данному вопросу я нашёл парочку вариантов:
1)v8i.hh + v8istd.hh
(https://atwillys.de/content/cc/cpp-google-v8-javascript-engine-interface-class-template/?lang=en)
2)v8pp (https://github.com/pmed/v8pp)

К сожалению, мне не удалось применить ни один из них: первый (API которого мне понравился больше), похоже, несколько устарел, а v8pp, судя по недвусмысленному `#include <node.h>`, похоже, ориентирован на Node.js (v8pp мне тоже не удалось запустить).

Таким образом, хотелось бы узнать:
1)Если вам приходилось использовать любую из этих библиотек - как именно вы её подготавливали к использованию?
2)Есть ли аналоги этим двум библиотекам и какие именно (если есть)?
3)В идеале, есть ли (извините за грубую аналогию между Js движком и xml парсером) для v8 API, настолько же более удобный, насколько Boost property_tree+xml_parser удобнее rapidXml? Если "да" - что это за библиотека?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось найти подходящую обёртку для v8. Вернее - запустить одну из ранее указанных мной - v8pp (https://github.com/pmed/v8pp).

Моё предположение относительно v8pp и Node.js оказалось ошибочным: v8pp *может* использоваться для добавления функциональности в Node.js, но *не нуждается в NodeJS*: достаточно просто v8 (что мне изначально и требовалось).

Причина того, что прежде мне не удавалось воспользоваться v8pp - невнимательность - неправильно прописал путь к заголовочным файлам. Правильный путь к заголовочным файлам (подразумевается что в папке с решением, в подпапке packages находится папка v8pp, непосредственно содержащая все подключаемые файлы) может быть прописан 
непосредственно как `$(SolutionDir)packages`. `$(SolutionDir)packages/v8pp` - неправильный вариант, ставший причиной моей изначальной проблемы - удавалось подключать требуемые header-ы, но его внутренние includ-ы не находили нужные файлы, что и было причиной проблемы.

На всякий случай добавлю, что v8pp по умолчанию - header-only, а .lib-ы - это дополнительная функциональность - если случайно не заметили данный пункт в документации - он там есть.